# How to slice big picture on small pieces (256x256) for PhotoScroller

Tags: iphone, photoshop

I have a big picture (3000x3000)pixels.  How can i slice it on small pieces (256x256)?

Comment: Do you mean at runtime or compile time? Is it in a file or in a UIImage, or even NSData? What code do you already have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to do this at build time, rather than run time, try using the ImageMagick '[crop](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?ImageMagick=v2onlhjloi9n3mte4325sjrf56#crop)' option

```
convert -crop 256x256 myoriginal.png mytiles_%d.png
```

Comment: Paul Dixon, thank you very much. It's cool tool. It begins from first row , then second row , the third row.   But i need to begin from 1 column , then 2 column , ... Can i do this ?